# How do I add something to the end of "}" if a pattern is matched?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

If I have something that looks like this:

```
hello {sdsdsdsds} pattern {askjdasjkdjasd} hello {siadsd} pattern {iuewer}
```

So if pattern if matched before `{*}`, I need to add a `;`. Output:

```
hello {sdsdsdsds} pattern {askjdasjkdjasd}; hello {siadsd} pattern {iuewer};
```

And this is just one lines, yes.

Now, I though of something like this:

```
's{.*}/
```

But I can't quite figure out how to make `sed` remember the contents of `.*`.

Then theres this,

```
'/pattern\ {.*}/ s/$/;/'
```

But this won't work since it is only one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question you are looking for

```
sed 's/\(pattern {[^}]*}\)/\1;/g'
```

where `\1` replaces everything what matched inside `\(...\)`.

The output:

```
hello {sdsdsdsds} pattern {askjdasjkdjasd}; hello {siadsd} pattern {iuewer};
```

Comment: To be more short strip `{` : `sed 's/pattern[^}]*}/&;/g'`